# SimpleSAMLphp integration with asp.net web form application

Tags: webforms, single-sign-on, saml

I have idp in simpleSAMLphp and want to use credentials of idp via single sign on in asp.net web form application.

Could you please help me with solutions?

How should I go with implementing asp.net web form client which will use credentials of idp and login to asp.net web form application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a commercial solution I suggest taking a look at our SAML for ASP.NET solutions ([www.componentspace.com/saml](http://www.componentspace.com/saml)). We include examples of using the SAML subject and/or SAML attributes contained in the SAML assertion to automatically log the user into an ASP.NET web forms application. There should be no interoperability issues with SimpleSAMLphp.

Comment: I wanted to implement it with open source. Could you please provide some solution with open source?